# How to use file_get_contents for my site

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have some problem when i want use file_get_content when i use www.google.com in file get content it work but if i call my web in local server it doesn't work. my local server connect vpn server.
this my code php

```
echo file_get_contents("https://omg-indonesia.softether.net:88/gammu/kirim.php");
```

and this my error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://omg-indonesia.softether.net:88/gammu/kirim.php): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/vmxtmjbe/public_html/web.php on line 320
```

please help me solve my problem

Comment: Have you tried to use CURL instead of file_get_contents ?

Comment: i use curl but also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It could be an execution problem, the size of the site matters. Try this

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Experiment with it a bit, maybe 300 is too much.

Comment: just put it as is  at the start of your file. More info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php